# WizardForm in Spring 3

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, wizard

I found a code from Spring forums that seems to be an interesting way to implement wizardForms in Spring 3:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView processSubmit(
@ModelAttribute("pet") Pet pet,
SessionStatus status) {
    if (pet.getFieldOne() == null) {
        //return the form that will set field one's value
        return new ModelAndView( ... );
    } else if (pet.getFieldTwo() == null) {
        //return the form that will set field two's value
        return new ModelAndView( ... );
    } //and so on for all the other field that need to be set...
    ...
    else {
        //once the object has all necessary fields
        //set and validated, then do what needs
        //to be done to finish. Store object, end
        //session, and return your success view.
        this.clinic.storePet(pet);
        status.setComplete();
        return new ModelAndView( ... );
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what the storing here means, and is this a good way?

Answer (score 0):

If by "storing" you mean `this.clinic.storePet(pet);`, it's an action of saving the complete object in your database when wizard is finished, so that it's completely unrelated to wizard implementation.

The approach itself is a standard way to implement wizard forms in Spring 3 that replaces the deprectated `AbstractWizardFormController`.

Note that it also requires `@SessionAttribute("pet")` as a class-level annotation. This annotation makes Spring to store the corresponding model attribute in the session between requests, so that each form submission sets fields of the same object. When all fields are set and wizard is finished, object is saved to the database, and removed from the session by `status.setComplete();`.

Comment: But if I create the model attribute object for the first form page, how it is ever null?

Comment: @mjgirl: The object is not `null`. Its fields are `null`, because they are not set.

Comment: Really? My code  public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("giveForm") GiveForm giveForm, SessionStatus status) {
        if (giveForm.getKeyId()==null) {
            return "give";
        }
        else {
       System.out.println(giveForm.getKeyId());
  status.setComplete();
  return "give-r";

Comment: does not ever return give -view

Comment: And one question still: is it easy to implement cancel and previous buttons with this?

Comment: @mjgirl: Yes. The easiest way is to add a hidden field with a step number to each form, and route different buttons to different methods as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119769/selectively-binding-a-property-in-spring-mvc/4119836#4119836). Then, given the step number from hidden field, in the back method you can return a view corresponding to the previous step. In cancel method you can clear the session by calling `status.setComplete();`.